# Cassandra Java Driver error - All host(s) tried for query failed Connection has been closed

Tags: cassandra, digital-ocean, datastax-enterprise, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

All,

I  have a 3 noded cluster cassandra in Digital Ocean . the version of cassandra as per **SHOW VERSION** in CQL is shown below

**[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.0.0 | CQL spec 3.3.1 | Native protocol v4]**

I am able to connnect to one node of the cluster from another node using cqlsh and run commands... However when i try to connect using the java driver , i get the following exception

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: /128.xxx.xxx.xx:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.TransportException: [/128.xxx.xxx.xxx:9042] Connection has been closed))
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.reconnectInternal(ControlConnection.java:222)
at com.datastax.driver.core.ControlConnection.connect(ControlConnection.java:77)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster$Manager.init(Cluster.java:1232)
at com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster.getMetadata(Cluster.java:336)
at com.attinad.cantiz.iot.platform.vehicledatapoc.App.connect(App.java:22)
at com.attinad.cantiz.iot.platform.vehicledatapoc.App.main(App.java:14)
```

The version of java driver that i am using is 2.0.10. The maven configuration is given below

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
<artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
<version>2.0.10</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked the cassandra.yaml and found that the following settings has been set correctly

```
start_native_transport: true
native_transport_port: 9042
rpc_address: 128.xxx.xxx.xx
listen_address: 128.xxx.xxx.xx
```

has been configured correctly... So i am completely lost... Any help is appreciated

Comment: Do you see anything in the Cassandra server output? I think the 2.0 Java drivers are not compatible with Cassandra 3.0. You should see an error in the server logs if this is the case.

Comment: That  was the reason. When i used the 3.0.0 beta driver, it started to work, but the driver is in beta version, So I am a little concerned

Comment: I have no experience with the stability of the driver,  but I think the safest thing would be to use Cassandra 2 with the released driver for a system which should be used in production. If you are just trying out Cassandra, using the beta driver might be OK.

Comment: I've made my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [2.0.10 driver documentation](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/2.0.10/#compatibility), that version of the driver is compatible with Apache Cassandra 1.2 and 2.0. Compatibility with 3.0 is added in the [3.0 driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/3.0.0-beta1#compatibility), which is currently at 3.0.0-beta1. The protocol compatibility error should be shown in the Cassandra server logs.

You could either downgrade Cassandra to a 2.x version or try out the beta driver. Downgrading Cassandra should be the safer choice if you want to use the system in production now.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself... had tried Cassandra 3.0.0 with driver 2.1.9.

Fixed it by going to driver 3.0.0.